# Faça um Programa que verifique se uma letra digitada é vogal ou consoante

Tags: python-3.x

```
alfa = input("Informe uma letra ou consoante:")

if alfa =="a":
    print("Vogal")
elif alfa == "e":
    print("Vogal")
elif alfa == "i":
    print("Vogal")
elif alfa == "o":
    print("Vogal")
elif alfa == "u":
    print("Vogal")
    print("Insira uma letra ou consoante")
else:
    print("Consoante")
```

Como faço para ele aceitar somente vogal ou consoante. Porque se o usuário informar um número o programa vai dizer que é uma consoante.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a método de string **.isalpha()**.
Ex.:

```
alfa = input("Informe uma letra ou consoante:")

if alfa.isalpha():
    if alfa =="a":
        print("Vogal")
    elif alfa == "e":
        print("Vogal")
    elif alfa == "i":
        print("Vogal")
    elif alfa == "o":
        print("Vogal")
    elif alfa == "u":
        print("Vogal")
        print("Insira uma letra ou consoante")
    else:
        print("Consoante")
else:
    print("Não é uma letra!")
```

Assim, seu código deve funcionar! Perceba a utilização do método alfa.**isalpha()**.
A documentação do python é bem completa, tenta sempre dar uma lida nela quando estiver com dúvidas!

[Link para a documentação acerca de strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str)